# Looking for a SMART json prettyprinter js library

Tags: javascript, php, json, pretty-print

I know ton of library can prettyprint json just by indenting/newline stuff but here is a line of my heavy json:

```
"Shape6":{"bounds_start":[0,-6,0],"bounds_end":[3,1,3],"origin":[2,15,-1],"mirror":true,"rotation":[0,0,0.837758],"uv":[15,30]}
```

All the libraries i found output something like this:

```
  "Shape6": {
   "bounds_start": [
     0,
     -6,
     0
   ],
   "bounds_end": [
     3,
     1,
     3
   ],
   "origin": [
     2,
     15,
     -1
   ],
   "mirror": true,
   "rotation": [
     0,
     0,
     0.837758
   ],
   "uv": [
     15,
     30
   ]
 }
```

But i'm looking for a more human-readable way which not add new lines for small arrays that can fit in a line like:

```
"Shape6": {
   "bounds_start": [0, -6, 0],
   "bounds_end": [3, 1, 3],
   "origin": [2, 15, -1],
   "mirror": true,
   "rotation": [0, 0, 0.837758],
   "uv": [15, 30]
}
```

i do want this because my json file is like 6k+ lines on the first example
if you know a js or a php library (for ajax purposes)

i thank you in advance (and sorry for my poor english :))

Comment: I've written one for my own use. You can find the code here: https://github.com/slebetman/json-poll. The file that implements the pretty printing is `json-prettify.js`. Alternatively you can use my program directly to load your JSON data from a url. I use it to poll internal server stats

Comment: Note: My code outputs HTML but you can easily edit it out

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do that with using JSON.stringify() function (see the reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

the first argument is the object you want to beautify, the second one is the function where we can specify the logic of line indention and new line breakings, the 3rd argument of this function (now 4) is the number for indention for your beautified JSON data

```
JSON.stringify(obj, function(k,v)
{
 if (v instanceof Array)
  return JSON.stringify(v);
  return v;
}, 4);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.